# Using where clause in PL/SQL with reserved word as column name

Tags: sql, plsql, where-clause

I have a column that is called CODE and that is a reserved word is PL/SQL so I am trying to select all using a where clause but it won't work. I used [ ] but it did not work. Is it different for PL/SQL?

```
select * 
from tab_i 
where [code] = 'jack'
```

Comment: Yes. Use quotation marks.

Comment: not clear at all

Comment: What does "it won't work" mean? Did you get any error? If so, which one? Also, code you posted is SQL, not PL/SQL so - I suggest you post code you really have, along with error stack.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `CODE` is not a reserved word in PL/SQL. So

```
select *
into my_record_variable 
from tab_i 
where code = 'jack';
```

or

```
select *
bulk collect into my_table_variable 
from tab_i 
where code = 'jack';
```

should work just fine.

Then, as to "Is it different for PL/SQL?": No. The same rules that apply for SQL delimiters apply for PL/SQL, too. Brackets, however, are not valid delimiters, neither in SQL nor in PL/SQL. The standard SQL delimiters for names are double quotes. (There exist DBMS, though, that are not standard compliant in this regard. SQL Server for instance uses brackets instead.)